# Shopify API call from App Proxy Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I need to make an API call from the Proxy App Controller. I know I need to retrieve my Session from Database after the User has Installed the APP, but I don't know how to do it?

I have a Rails / Heroku APP.

Thanks,
CR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every call from Shopify to your Proxy Endpoint provides security data you use to validate the call. You use that data to figure out who is calling. Since you're given the "Who", use that to open up a Session valid to make API calls for "Who" is calling. That is pretty much spelled out in the documentation on validating App Proxy calls, which are validated the same as Webhook calls, another source of info for you if you find yourself lost.

Comment: Thanks David! Thanks for your support!